# I need help to create a specific view of content on smaller devices

Tags: html, css

Good day friends!

Please, I need a guide or put-through on how to achieve a particular view or display on Mobile device of "viewport: 320 x 568px" as such; [Here's the screen view of the UI Bug on the aforementioned viewport.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBsw6.jpg)

Having used my Browser(Chrome Browser) to inspect the codes elements, I found this codes:

```
<div class="col-sm-1" style="margin-top:30px;">

<span style="height: 200px;
                            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
                            padding-bottom: 157px;"></span>
<br>
<p style="    padding-top: 171px;
                            margin-left: -6px;">OR</p>
<br>
<span style="height: 200px;
                            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
                            padding-bottom: 157px;"></span>
```

Then I did some tweak, adjustments on the code above, hence, I came up with this:

```
<div class="col-sm-1" style="margin-top:30px;">

<span style="
                            height: 20px;
                            border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
                            padding-right: 100px;
                            " class=""></span>
<br>
<p style="
                            margin-left: 91px;
                            ">OR</p>
<span style="
                            height: 20px;
                            border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
                            padding-right: 100px;
                        "></span>
```

Then after the tweak and adjustments, [I achieved this result thereafter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuA6v.jpg)

Now, my whole challenge is to bring all this tweak into a viewport of "@media screen and (max-width: 480px)" in the style sheet of the website. The problem being this whole tweak is done on a html page, which if I go straight to edit it there and update with what I have come up with, it will affect other viewports, which will be a big issue for me.

So, my good friends, how to do I put that tweak to work on the said viewport in the style sheet without altering other viewports?

I shall await your wonderful replies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is my solution after much cracking of my cranium for solution.

I moved to the HTML page, and edit the code or tag responsible for that content like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 text-center">

    <span style="height: 20px;
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 12px;"></span>
    <p style="    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-left: -6px;">OR</p>
    <span style="height: 20px;
    border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 12px;"></span>
</div>
```

Then inside the CSS file, I just added a **padding-top:200px** attribute to the @media (min-width: 768px) to avoid distortion on small screen less than 768px wide. So on my CSS file, I just looked for the **min-width: 768px with col-sm-1** element, which is of course in the CSS file and added just the padding attribute, which is:

```
.col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
    padding-top:    200px;
}
```

And voila! This solves my challenge and everybody is happy again.